# Getting blank json during heavy workload

Tags: mongodb

We are facing this issue since last month. here in our case, we have used nodejs version 6.11 and monogdb npm version 1.4.28.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVMKw.png)

In the above screenshot, logs are displayed as blank json. Socket server is getting crashed due to this error.

For the resolution, we have handled the error with below code:

Code with handled error:
[temporary fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqfcD.png)

Code while error came and server got crashed:
[Before Crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrZVZ.png)

We can not handle this error as this have been used at n number of places.

Can anyone help me resolving this issue?

Thanks in advance.

-

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Pranav. Would you be able to include logs and code as embedded elements of your post, as opposed to linked images? It would make your question remain relevant if the hosted images are no longer available. Thank you

Comment: can you please provide your node js Code with which MongoDB module you use

Comment: @TonySepia We were logging the error with the wrong method. We have found the error and it is "No replica set primary available for query with ReadPreference PRIMARY". Can you please help me what it is denoting?

We have used a replica set of 3 nodes and mongodb version is 3.2.20.